# i write a wrong spider , yet can not find out, who can correct the code?

Tags: scrapy

Spider code is wrong. I created a demon project, but it does not work, kindly check my vs code shot cut & I have no idea for all my spider code and problems.

```
import scrapy

class EmailSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='Email'

    start_url = [
        'http://jsjy.114chn.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self,response):
        for Email in response.xpath("//span[@id='lblEmail']"):
            yiel{
                'email_text': Email.xpath(".//span[@id='lblEmail_text']/p").extract_first()
            }

         next_page= response.xpath("//li[@class='next']/a/@href").extract_first()
         if next_page is not None:
             next_page_link= response.urljoin(next_page)
             yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with indentation and `yield` function. Also made some code-style  corrections:

```
import scrapy


class EmailSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Email'
    start_url = ['http://jsjy.114chn.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for email in response.xpath("//span[@id='lblEmail']"):
            yield {
                'email_text': email.xpath(".//span[@id='lblEmail_text']/p").get()
            }

        next_page = response.xpath("//li[@class='next']/a/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page))
```

But since you don't have any `#lblEmail` elements on page, this spider will not output anything.